# Which is better: clone a repo and push to new location or just branch it?

Tags: git, github, fork, branch

I created a repo which will serve as a starting point for all of my web app projects. Each time I would create a new web app out of that starting point, should I clone the original and push it to a new repo, or would it be better to create a branch out of it (without intending to merge it back with the master)?

Also, should I opt for branching it instead, if I update my original (master) repo will the updates cascade to all my branches? I am wondering if the branches only retain the version of the repo at the time the branch was created or will it also receive all future commits pushed to the master.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

While not built directly into Git itself, GitHub has [template repositories](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-template-repository) which would fit your purpose perfectly. When creating a new repository on GitHub, you will be given the option to make it from the template, which you could then pull back to your machine.